# disable js for mobile view in wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I want to disable extra JavaScript functions for my WordPress website , because speed of my website is very slow for small screens. i did use multiple plugins for cache, image optimization and for minimizing the JavaScript and Css.Even though I compressed all the JavaScript and  Css but its still really slow for mobile devices ,**Can you refer me some plugin for disabling JavaScript for mobile views in WordPress, if there is no such a plugin i will go with custom coding**..Thank you...

Answer (score 2):

Use wordpress [wp_is_mobile()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) function.This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate window.innerWidth and do this

```
if(window.innerWidth > 767) {// you can mention your own width.
    //Write all your js code  here.
}
```